# Q : Pebble + AppMessage delivers empty dictionary

Tags: c

I'm trying to add some configuration to a watchface I developped, but reached a complete standstill.  The configuration takes you to a page where one must select a city.  I've added a app.js page which catches this value & redirects it to the watchface :

```
Pebble.addEventListener("webviewclosed",
  function(e) {
    //Get JSON dictionary
    var configuration = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(e.response));
    console.log("[DBUG] Configuration window returned: " + JSON.stringify(configuration) + " " + configuration.basic);

    //Send to Pebble, persist there
    Pebble.sendAppMessage(
      {'KEY_CITY': configuration.basic},
      function(e) {
        console.log("[DBUG] Settings data sent successfully ");
      },
      function(e) {
        console.log("[FAIL] Settings feedback failed!");
      }
    );
  }
```

);

This works great, and the logs contain the correct selected city.  I also notice the in_recv_handler callback function is called :

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: Skylines__0.0/pebble-js-app.js:12 [DBUG]     Configuration window returned: {"basic":"Brussels"} Brussels
[DEBUG] main.c:106: [DBUG] in_recv_handler - EMPTY TUPLE
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: Skylines__0.0/pebble-js-app.js:18 [DBUG] Settings data sent successfully
```

In my C code, things go horribly wrong :
The appmessage seems correctly initialised in the init() part :

```
app_message_register_inbox_received(in_recv_handler);
  app_message_register_inbox_dropped(inbox_dropped);
  app_message_open(app_message_inbox_size_maximum(), app_message_outbox_size_maximum());
```

The in_recv_handler is where the problem is :

```
static void in_recv_handler(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context) {

  //Get data
  Tuple *tup = dict_read_first(iterator);
  if (tup != NULL) {  
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "[DBUG] in_recv_handler - NONEMPTY TUPLE");
    process_tuple(tup);
  }
  else { APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "[DBUG] in_recv_handler - EMPTY TUPLE"); }
}
```

The tuple/dictionary is allways empty.  So it seems something in between the app.js and the loading of the dictionary goes wrong, but I haven't any clue here....